# Creating a background-image gradient triangle that is horizontally centered

Tags: html, css

I want to create a triangle pointing down in css by using `clip-path: polygon(...)` and apply a gradient on it using `background-image: linear-gradient(...)`.

This all works fine but I need this shape as the background of my web page.

It needs to always be centered and it needs to clip/cut off the left and right edges that do not fit in the browser window. The triangle should not re-scale itself; I want to preserve the steepness of the triangle's edges and **the height of the triangle should not change**:

[image]

As illustrated, the triangle should stay the same width and height even when the browser window is too small to contain it.

So far I have:

```css
    div.main-background {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0;
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #65AAB0, #AEE2B6);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position-x: center; 
        background-size: 1400px 500px;
        clip-path: polygon(50% 80%, 0 0, 1400px 0);   
    }
```

```html
    <div class="main-background"></div>
```

but this is clearly wrong.

Comment: If the height of the triangle should not change and the triangle should not rescale itself, as you put it, then what you are expressing is effectively the requirement that the triangle has constant aspect ratio and either height or width defined as `em`, `px` or other unit that doesn't depend on e.g. a viewport dimension.

Comment: @amn yes that seems about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with SVG

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1920 400" height="400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#65AAB0"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#AEE2B6"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="0,0 960,400 1920,0" fill="url(#Gradient1)"></polygon>
</svg>
```

Comment: I like it but is there anyway to keep the height of the triangle fixed? It seems to scale itself which is a problem.

Comment: is there anyway of changing the size of the polygon? I need to have it very wide (like 1200px and down by 400px) but cannot figure out how to do this with the code.

Comment: Yes you can change the `<svg>`'s `viewBox` and the `<polygon>`'s points attribute.

Comment: Thanks! I've played around with it but if I needed the width to be very large, say 1920px to fit most screens, how would I do this? I tried changing the `120` value to `200` thinking that would mean 2000px but then it breaks (it is no longer centered)

Comment: I've edited the answer again to use values that should make better sense to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184334/discussion-between-ksav-and-mayron).

Answer (score 1):

Using viewport units, is this what you want? Works on any resolution.

```css
div.main-background {
       position: absolute;
       z-index: -1;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       height: 35.71vw;
       background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #65AAB0, #AEE2B6);
       background-attachment: fixed;
       background-position: center; 
       clip-path: polygon(50% 80%, 0 0, 100vw 0);  
    }
```

```html
<div class="main-background"></div>
```

Comment: It's definitely nicer but I was hoping to not scale the triangle but just trim/clip the left and right areas that no longer fit in the new browser width. So the triangle's height should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try multiple background like below. I made the triangle to have a width of `600px` and a height of `300px`that you can easily adjust.

```css
body {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) calc(50% + 150px) 0 /300px 300px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) calc(50% - 150px) 0 /300px 300px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #65AAB0, #AEE2B6)top center/ 600px 300px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Easier with CSS variable :

```css
body {
  --w:800px;
  --h:300px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) calc(50% + calc(var(--w)/4)) 0 /calc(var(--w)/2) var(--h),
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) calc(50% - calc(var(--w)/4)) 0 /calc(var(--w)/2) var(--h),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #65AAB0, #AEE2B6)top center/ var(--w) var(--h);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This looks really promising. I'm having difficulties getting it to work in my div (rather than the body) but won't give up. Will let you know how I get on, ty.

Comment: @Mayron be sure your div has a height defined or is taller enough to contain the background

Answer (score 1):

You are going about it the wrong way. Your `div` contains no content and is thus simply decorative cruft. If you want a page background of certain appearance, then whatever appearance the background should have, goes into the `background` property of the document element (typically `body`, or `html`).

Get rid of your useless `div.main-background` which serves no purpose whatsoever, and use the following background image, either standalone (in its own SVG file) or inline using a `data:` URI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
    <polygon fill="lime" points="0,0 0.5,0.4 1,0" />
</svg>
```

The following CSS declaration will use the above as a background image, from your explanation the background size should be a definite length (as opposed to one relative to viewport dimensions), I will use `40em` because I didn't pick any clues from your question:

```
body {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1 1"><polygon fill="lime" points="0,0 0.5,0.4 1,0" /></svg>');
    background-size: 40em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a standalone SVG file, then your `background` rule will be different:

```
background: url(<URL-of-SVG-file>);
```

You can add the gradient easily by editing SVG content, it's a basic SVG feature, one of the other answers here even demonstrates how.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is there anyway of setting the exact width and height of the triangle in your example? I changed `background-size: 40em;` to `background-size: 1200px 400px` thinking that would change the width to 1200px and height to 400px but all that did was make it smaller.

Comment: Wait a minute -- I thought you wanted original aspect ratio? Why are you specifying two values for `background-size`? You are scaling your background image *non-uniformly* then. If you want to have image rendered smaller, then provide a single value smaller than `40em`. If you want to absolutely decide on either background's width or height, use `background-size-x` and `background-size-y`, respectively, but I'd still like to know exactly how you want your background to behave? Update your question, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use that kind of trick with just CSS and an `after` pseudo-element:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.arrow-down {
  --w:800px;
  --h:300px;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--w); 
  height: var(--h);
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #65AAB0, #AEE2B6);
}

.arrow-down::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: calc(var(--h)/2) calc(var(--w)/2);
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</body>
```

Of course, you can tweak width and height to better suit your needs.

Comment: but it's not centred and it's scaling